# How to sync Core Data with referenced files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, icloud

Just started to read various posts how to sync files or core data using iCloud. The app I'm currently developing stores data inside core data and filenames as references to the image files stored in documents app sandbox. So, a related file (photo) is also created in documents dir every time a user makes a record inside a database.

Everything looks fine if we would need to sync files OR core data, however I'm looking a way how to sync core data AND files. So, I'm worried about the case if new core data records will arrive earlier than image files of those records. In that case, data integrity will be broken. Actually, I would prefer all new related files would come first, and then all core data updates. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no. You send data to the cloud, but you have no way to control when it appears on other devices. iCloud is going to bring over your managed objects whenever it feels like it, regardless of the state of the external files. The only way you could make this happen would be to find and download any external files, wait for the download to finish, and only then bring up your Core Data stack. But that would mean locking the user out of the data store until the downloads finish, which is not a good idea.

When I faced a similar situation, I handled it like this:

- Initiate downloads of all the external files and bring up the Core Data stack.
- Modify the getter method for the image to check whether the file exists and has been downloaded.

  - If yes to both, proceed normally
  - If no, display a "loading..." UI element. This could be a spinner or a progress indicator. Listen for a custom "download complete" notification.
- Whenever an external file finishes downloading, post that "download complete" notification. Re-check the file, and if it's ready, replace the "loading..." UI with the image.